# What is meaning of domain and default function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, rickshaw

What is meaning of `defaults: function($super)` and `domain: function($super)` in javascript?. The following code is taken from [openstack-horizon](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/horizon/static/horizon/js/horizon.d3linechart.js#L164-194). They are using very high level of javascript concept but I know basic of javascript.

```
Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.StaticAxes = Rickshaw.Class.create(Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Line, {      
  name: 'StaticAxes',
  defaults: function($super) {
    alert("13 => This is repeated many time. Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.StaticAxes");
    return Rickshaw.extend($super(), {
      xMin: undefined,
      xMax: undefined,
      yMin: undefined,
      yMax: undefined
    });
  },
  domain: function($super) {
    //alert("HJ");
    var ret = $super();
    var xMin, xMax;
    // If y axis wants to have static range, not based on data
    if (this.yMin !== undefined && this.yMax !== undefined) {
      ret.y = [this.yMin, this.yMax];
    }
    // If x axis wants to have static range, not based on data
    if (this.xMin !== undefined && this.xMax !== undefined) {
      xMin = d3.time.format.utc('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').parse(this.xMin);
      xMin = xMin.getTime() / 1000;
      xMax = d3.time.format.utc('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').parse(this.xMax);
      xMax = xMax.getTime() / 1000;

      ret.x = [xMin, xMax];
    }
    return ret;
  }
});
```

Comment: Both statements are assigning functions to an object literal key. When you call `defaults` it will call the function assigned. When you call `domain` it will call the other function. For more info, refer to **Object Literals**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code.

```
var objectLiteral = {
    variable: "I'm a string",
    fun: function(param) {
        console.log("I'm a function.");
        console.log("Here's the param: ", param);
    }
}

console.log(objectLiteral);
objectLiteral.fun();
```

`fun` and `variable` are fields of the object literal.
`function()` syntax is used to declare a function, which get assigned to `fun`.